# Insight: Deprecated APIs removed in Kubernetes v1.29

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade, amazon-eks, deprecated

We have EKS cluster for production with K8s version 1.28. We have to upgrade the version to 1.29 but stucked because of following error showing in AWS Console in Upgrade insights section:

[AWS Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTQjN.png)

I can see all the apis versions are already up to date but not getting why this error is showing in the console. We have risk of downtime if we upgrade by ingnoring the error.

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.